# ¿Cómo usar nest como intermediario entre angular y mis servicios web, particularmente con métodos de tipo post?

Tags: typescript

Actualmente tengo mi aplicación en angular y mis servicios web get y post respectivamente en rest (se consumen normalmente por medio de postman). El problema que tengo es que según la arquitectura debo utilizar nestjs como intermediario entre angular y mis servicios web.
He tratado usando axios pero no he resuelto mi problema, te agradecería si me das alguna luz en este tema.

---

```js
import { Controller,
         Get,
         Post,
         HttpService,
         Body,
         HttpCode,
         HttpStatus,
         Res,
         Param,
         Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessageDto } from '../dto/mensaje-dto';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Controller('/profile')
export class FooController {

    constructor(
        private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    ) {}

    @Post('create')
    createMessage(@Body() message: MessageDto){
      //const params=JSON.stringify(message);
        return this.httpService.post("url",
        message,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }).pipe(map((res) => {
      return res.data;
    }));
    }

   @Get('/buscarId/:claroId')
    async buscarClaroId(@Param('claroId') claroId: string, @Query() params): Promise<any>
    {
      //const response = await this.httpService.get('url'+claroId+'?filter='+params.filter).toPromise();
      return response.data;
    }


}
```

Comment: tienes al menos algun codigo de lo que has realizado para implementar???

Comment: Claro que si. en Nestjs este es mi codigo: @Post('create')
    createMessage(@Body() message: MessageDto){
      //const params=JSON.stringify(message);
        return this.httpService.post("url",
        message,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }).pipe(map((res) => {
      return res.data;
    }));
    }

Comment: Ese post planeo consumirlo desde angular

Comment: puedes alctualizar tu pregunta con la opcion de ditar y agregar todo lo que tienes por favor. no es legible en elos comentarios.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con el que te enfrentas? La documentación en Nestjs deja en claro que usa de Axios para su servicio HttpService, el cual ya estas implementando, lo unico que te quedaría por hacer es regresar el observable que regresa el servicio, en este caso basta con eliminar la implementación del *pipe* que tienes, y regresar un  Observable<AxiosResponse<any[]>> como lo marca la [documentación](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module).

Comment: Necesito consumir mis servicios web de nestjs en angular 8, estoy buscando como realizar esa parte de unir el BFF con mi frontend

Comment: Añadiendo al comentario de @OscarLudick, creo que lo que estás buscando es implementar un [servicio](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4). De una u otra forma, las consultas retornatán un [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular) el cual necesariamente tienes que y/o controlar.